# Function throws error: Out of memory happened while accessing a critical resource

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I received this error when trying to send characters to this function:

```
SELECT dbo.AnsiToUnicode('ABCD')
```

> AppDomain MyDB.dbo[runtime].203 was unloaded by escalation policy to
>   ensure the consistency of your application. Out of memory happened
>   while accessing a critical resource.

Can please someone advise on that.

My SQL Server version is (2005) 9.00.4053.00

Thanks

Comment: I am not familiar with this function.  Why don't you just use `cast('ABCD' as nvarchar(255))` or something like that?

Comment: Actually this is in a stored procedure created and running since ages. this function works fine in other servers, but on a server it gives me error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the end of the error message: `Out of memory happened while accessing a critical resource`.

The error has to do with SQLCLR running out of available memory.

[Others have faced the same error.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlnetfx/thread/28441ecd-6845-40f0-9cb7-d28856cdc590/)

Also check out the [MS Support knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969962) relating to the error.  Most of the article points to reviewing & monitoring CLR memory usage.  I tried to paraphrase what would be most relevant but you'd be better reading through it yourself. :)